# Button outline is larger than button dimensions

Tags: css

I was trying to make a button with 3 dots. Though it came with weird problem. When you click on it, you will notice a weird "mountain" while it is in focus mode.

```css
button {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding-top: .4em;
  padding-bottom: .8em;
  line-height: 0;
  font-weight: 800;
  background: black;
  border: 0;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button>...</button>
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c1v634rb/)

How do I remove it or what is causing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "mountain" is there because the `font-size` is larger in height than the actual button. If you remove the text you'll notice the mountain is gone.

To fix this, you could simply add `overflow: hidden` to make sure the text doesn't clip through the button.

```css
button {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding-top: .4em;
  padding-bottom: .8em;
  line-height: 0;
  font-weight: 800;
  background: black;
  border: 0;
  color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button>...</button>
```

You also seem to have more `padding` than necessary, which seems to cause negative inner dimensions of your button and other "glitches". Double-check those.

Comment: Thanks, did not thought it could be a font-size and it kind of drived me nuts cause of it does not seemed like a complicated problem to solve but still... @_ @

Comment: And the padding thing, I did it this way cause normally without padding at the top and bottom with line-height:0;, it is not equal on both sides. https://jsfiddle.net/c1v634rb/1/  The dots are at the bottom in this example

Comment: @Harugawa the actual problem here is that `...` is a set of symbols that are aligned at the bottom of a line - not in the middle (like `-` for example). To fix this problem you can use `:after` or `:before` pseudo-classes which gives additional options when aligning an item. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/c1v634rb/2/) is a demo with fixed dimensions, including good padding. The key here is that the text `...` is **not** larger than it needs to be, so nothing is "pushed" - because I have forced a set `height` to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `outline: none`, although I'm not sure why the "mountain" is there in the first place. It happens only in Chrome though - Firefox seems fine.

Comment: Do not remove the outline, it's a key feature for accessibility.

Comment: Further to Roy's comment, you *can* remove the `outline`, but if you do so you really should replace that outline with another visual cue to show that the element is focused (whether using the `background-color`, `border-color`, `box-shadow`...) there really must be something for a non-mouse user to identify which element on the page is focused.