# How can I fix "larger" outline in firefox when line-height and font-size are increased?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, outline

I am using css from an external library (I have to use) to build a page. I came across the problem that the outline around an icon is larger (and spills over other elements) in firefox that it is in chrome.

I reduced it to a more minimalistic version and put it on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/73fu6L1q/

HTML:

```
<div class="somediv foo">
  &nbsp;
</div>

<div class="somediv bar">
  &nbsp;
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.somediv {
  background-image: url("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/700035-icon-77-document-file-css-16.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  outline-offset: 3px;
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-width: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}

.foo {
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 22px;
  outline-color: red;
}

.bar {
  outline-color: blue;
}
```

I assume it is somehow dependant on the line-height and/or font-size (or maybe this just increases the issue?) but have no idea how to make it look the same (or at least similar enough). Can anyone give me a hint on what to try or explain why this happens?

This is what the result on jsfiddle looks like for me:

[image: comparison chrome/ff]

Comment: The problem is the way you have it coded....you can see by just taking out the absolute positioning of the graphic then both will look the same after. You need to code it without doing position absolute because whatever your doing ...dont think you need to do it that way..

Comment: Well, it is not really _my_ code. This is taken from the external library I have to use. The issue I showed also happens on their demo page. But thank you, I'll see if fiddling around with position fixes the problem.

Edit: When I remove the _position: absolute_ from jsfiddle, it makes it full width and changes positioning, but the basic problem with the larger spacing between icon and outline in firefox remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Solution taken from this question: [Button outline is larger than button dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40318754/button-outline-is-larger-than-button-dimensions)

What ended up working for me was adding `overflow:hidden` to my button and now it's displaying at the correct height.